# Where does this .get(x) behavior come from?

Tags: scala, standard-library

```scala
Some("abcdefg").get(3)  //res0: Char = d
```

The argument to `get()` is sent to the `apply()` method of the `String`, but the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/Option.scala) for `Option` (and `Some`) doesn't have a `get()` method that takes parameters, and `String` has no `get` method at all.

So what `get()` is being invoked? Is it a mole from Java land?

Answer (score 6):

It is `StringOps.apply` from implicit conversion

```
augmentString(Some("abcdefg").get)(3)
```

where [`augmentString`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6b4d32c3f518d21a798e8d3cf4a8c35866afa8e2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L401) is

```
@inline implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in this case `.get(x)` is not a separate `get()` method but an abbreviation for `.get.apply(x)`. So it's the standard `get` method on the `Some` type. No implicits required.

```
Some(Seq(99,32,12,7,101)).get(3)  //res0: Int = 7
```

Many thanks to @Mario Galic for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Just one question here, does this mean that, a .get method creates a new copy of the wrapped string inside it

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar; The `get` method does no copying. Other things might be going on when the `apply()` is invoked, but the `get` itself is quite simple: `final case class Some[+A](value: A) extends Option[A] {def get: A = value}`